# XML expression to return attribute for a filtered value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to write an expression that will return the priority for for a filtered value. So far I've been able to get correct results when filtering for the attribute to return the value, but not the reverse. Any help with this?

//Test/FileTypes/FileType[@Priority = '10'] returns person

//Test/FileTypes/FileType/@Priority returns the three attribute values (10,11,20)

//Test/FileTypes/FileType[FileType = 'Person']/@Priority returns nothing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Test>
    <FileTypes>
        <FileType Priority="10">Person</FileType>
        <FileType Priority="11">Job</FileType>
        <FileType Priority="20">Check</FileType>
    </FileTypes>
</Test>
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation of the issue and for the correct expression. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `//Test/FileTypes/FileType[FileType =
>   'Person']/@Priority` returns nothing

**As it should**. A `FileType` doesn't have a child named `FileType`.

**Use**:

`/Test/FileTypes/FileType[.= 'Person']/@Priority`

Comment: @Jarek, `.` is the abbreviation for the context node (or for `self::node()`). `. = 'Person'` evaluates to the boolean value (true() of false()) of comparing the string value of the context node with the string `'Person'`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

**//Test/FileTypes/FileType[text() = 'Person']/@Priority**